# How to use web camera in webview in android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview

Hello there SO community!

I am working on an android webview app that uses the web camera.

It works perfectly on a website, but in my app it doesn't work properly.

[image: This is my error message.]

How I can overcome this problem?

I have wrote all the permissions in the manifest like the camera, read external, write external storage and internet access.

This is the complete code for my webview app.

```java
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ProgressBar loadingBar;
    WebView webView;
    private static final int TELEPHONY_REQUEST = 111;
    String imeiNumber;

    private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
    public ValueCallback<Uri[]> uploadMessage;
    public static final int REQUEST_SELECT_FILE = 100;
    private final static int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                String[] PERMISSIONS = {android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA};
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, PERMISSIONS, TELEPHONY_REQUEST );

        }else{
            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("Jainam_Software", MODE_PRIVATE);
            String uuid = prefs.getString("UUID", null);
            try {

                if (uuid == null) {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("Jainam_Software", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                    imeiNumber = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
                    editor.putString("UUID", imeiNumber);
                    editor.apply();
                }
                else{
                    imeiNumber = uuid;
                }
            }catch (Exception e)
            {
                if (uuid == null) {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("Jainam_Software", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                    imeiNumber = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
                    editor.putString("UUID", imeiNumber);
                    editor.apply();
                }else{
                    imeiNumber = uuid;
                }
            }


        Log.e("UUID Number",imeiNumber);

        loadingBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess( true );
        WebSettings mWebSettings = webView.getSettings();
        mWebSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        mWebSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        mWebSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()
        {
            // For 3.0+ Devices (Start)
            // onActivityResult attached before constructor
            protected void openFileChooser(ValueCallback uploadMsg, String acceptType)
            {
                mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Browser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
            }


            // For Lollipop 5.0+ Devices
            public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView mWebView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams)
            {
                if (uploadMessage != null) {
                    uploadMessage.onReceiveValue(null);
                    uploadMessage = null;
                }

                uploadMessage = filePathCallback;

                Intent intent = null;
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    intent = fileChooserParams.createIntent();
                }
                try
                {
                    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_SELECT_FILE);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e)
                {
                    uploadMessage = null;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cannot Open File Chooser", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }

            //For Android 4.1 only
            protected void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture)
            {
                mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "File Browser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
            }

            protected void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg)
            {
                mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
            }
        });
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {


                if (url.startsWith("tel:") || url.startsWith("mailto:") || url.startsWith("whatsapp:") || url.startsWith("facebook:")  )
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity( intent );
                    return true;
                }

                else{
                    view.loadUrl(url,getIEMEHeader());
                }
                return true;
            }

            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                if (loadingBar!=null) {
                    loadingBar.setProgress(0);
                    loadingBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }

            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {

                if (loadingBar!=null) {
                    loadingBar.setProgress(0);
                    loadingBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                view.loadData("<html><body style='vertical-align:center;'><br><br><div style='vertical-align:center;text-align:center'>This app requires internet connection.<br>For further assistance contact<br><a href=\"mailto:info@ggmfi.com?Subject=Need%20support\">+91 8220311778</a><br><br><br><a href=\"https://www.loans.ggmfi.com/admin/\">Go to Home Page</a></div></body></html>","text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);

            }
        });
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.loans.ggmfi.com/admin/");

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (webView!=null && webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.home:
                if (webView!=null) {
                    webView.loadUrl("https://www.loans.ggmfi.com/admin/");
                } break;
                default:break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private Map<String, String> getIEMEHeader()
    {
        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
        headers.put("IMEI", imeiNumber);
        return headers;
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case TELEPHONY_REQUEST: {
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("Jainam_Software", MODE_PRIVATE);
                    String uuid = prefs.getString("UUID", null);
                    try {

                        if (uuid == null) {
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("Jainam_Software", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                            imeiNumber = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
                            editor.putString("UUID", imeiNumber);
                            editor.apply();
                        }
                        else{
                            imeiNumber = uuid;
                        }
                    }catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        if (uuid == null) {
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("Jainam_Software", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                            imeiNumber = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
                            editor.putString("UUID", imeiNumber);
                            editor.apply();
                        }else{
                            imeiNumber = uuid;
                        }
                    }

                    this.startActivity(new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));

                } else {

                }
                return;
            }

        }
    }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.status_menu, menu);//Menu Resource, Menu
            return true;
        }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
    {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_SELECT_FILE)
            {
                if (uploadMessage == null)
                    return;
                uploadMessage.onReceiveValue(WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams.parseResult(resultCode, intent));
                uploadMessage = null;
            }
        }
        else if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE)
        {
            if (null == mUploadMessage)
                return;
            // Use MainActivity.RESULT_OK if you're implementing WebView inside Fragment
            // Use RESULT_OK only if you're implementing WebView inside an Activity
            Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != MainActivity.RESULT_OK ? null : intent.getData();
            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
            mUploadMessage = null;
        }
        else
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to Upload Image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Things have changed in the Android version 11

```
ActivityResultLauncher<String> cameraPermission = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission(), new ActivityResultCallback<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(Boolean result) {
                if(result)
                {
                    System.out.println("CAMERA PERMISSION GRANTED");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("CAMERA PERMISSION NOT GRANTED");
                }
            }
        });

        cameraPermission.launch(Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
```

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()
        {
            @Override
            public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request)
            {
                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
                {
                    request.grant(request.getResources());
                }
            }
        });
```

You can add the `ActivityResultLauncher` code and modify the `webView.setWebChromeClient` code inside the `OnCreate` method.

This will ask for camera permission and once you grant, the camera embedded inside your application will work.

Let me know if you have any queries in it.